# Python 3 PDF text extraction

Tags: python, python-3.x

I had recently switched from python 2 to python 3. I knew that PDFMiner module is not supported by python 3. So I wonder if there's alternative to PDFMiner or to put it simpler, whether there is any module that support Python 3 and is able to extract text and numbers from a pdf?

Comment: There is a free linux program doing what you want from command line

Answer (score 9):

Pdfminer3k should be exactly that:

> pdfminer3k is a Python 3 port of pdfminer. PDFMiner is a tool for
>   extracting information from PDF documents

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfminer3k

Comment: Thanks a lot for the concise answer, was looking for this for a long time.